# How can I get rid of dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following dynamic SQL in one of my package bodies

```
 OPEN ccur for
    'select c.category 
     from test_category c 
     where c.deptid='||PI_N_Dept ||
     ' and c.category not in ('|| sExcludeCategories ||')';
```

`sExcludeCategories` will contain a set of integers separated by comma. I would like to eliminate this dynamic SQL statement. Are there any smart ways to accomplish this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you know you can bind a variable to `PI_N_Dept` to remove that piece of dynamic sql. Unfortunately for your `IN` clause and `sExcludeCategories` you can't bind a variable for a list in Oracle (at least up to 9.2 as far as i know)

You do have a few choices. Your current solution is the easiest. Another solution is to change the procedure to accept multiple variables and create a list of AND statements.

```
'select c.category 
     from test_category c 
     where c.deptid= :PI_N_Dept
       and c.category <> :sExcludeCategory1 
       and c.category <> :sExcludeCategory2
       and c.category <> :sExcludeCategory3

';
```

or have a fixed list of IN values

```
'select c.category 
     from test_category c 
     where c.deptid= :PI_N_Dept
       and c.category not in (:sExcludeCategory1 , :sExcludeCategory2, :sExcludeCategory3)';
```

You'll have to be careful in the case where you only want 2 categories. The third will have to be set to some value not in c.category (NB: be careful and test null values here)

Another solution is presented in [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061). This looks quite simple, though i haven't tested it. It works by creating a function str2tbl() which allows you to pass a series of numbers separated by commas and creating a 'table' via dual to do a IN.

```
create or replace type myTableType as table of number;

create or replace function str2tbl( p_str in varchar2 ) return myTableType
  as
     l_str   long default p_str || ',';
     l_n        number;
     l_data    myTableType := myTabletype();
  begin
      loop
          l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
          exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
          l_data.extend;
          l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
          l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
      end loop;
      return l_data;
  end;
```

Your example would look something like

```
'select c.category 
     from test_category c 
     where c.deptid= :PI_N_Dept
       and c.category not in ( select * from INLIST ( select cast( str2tbl( :sExcludeCategories  ) as mytableType ) from dual ) )';
```

This would only work if `sExcludeCategories` was a list of numbers. You'd have to change str2tbl to handle quotes if they are included in the variable (and you cant change it) plus change the type of `myTableType` to `varchar2(10)` or something more appropriate.

Overall, if the original sql not effecting performance then for simplicity sake i'd leave it as dynamic SQL. It's much less of a head ache to maintain. Otherwise test out the str2tbl. It should work in Oracle 8 and above.

**PS**: Just for completeness, i came across [this nice article on binding vars](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) that covers the simple problems like though not using variables for IN clauses.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer.
With a little tweak, I'll be able to solve the problem.

Comment: In general, this is a very good answer.  However, I strongly disagree with your statement about leaving it as dynamic SQL.  Using string concatenation to create your SQL leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know oracle, but in SQL Server, it is fairly common to obtain a "split" udf ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql/2677#2677) - just one of many, many versions available) that turns the CSV into a column of values, and join (etc) to it. Does pl-sql have anything similar?

Comment: Sadly there is no tokenizer in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace type numbertype
as object
(nr number(20,10) )
/ 

create or replace type number_table
as table of numbertype
/ 

create or replace procedure tableselect
( p_numbers in number_table
, p_ref_result out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
  open p_ref_result for
    select *
    from employees , (select /*+ cardinality(tab 10) */ tab.nr from table(p_numbers) tab) tbnrs 
    where id = tbnrs.nr; 
end; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like that:

```
OPEN ccur for
  select c.category 
  from test_category c 
  where 
    c.deptid= PI_N_Dept
    and c.category not in 
    (select category_id from categories where <some-condition-that-finds-the-categories-that-should-be-excluded>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by bulk-copying your values into a temporary table, and joining against that. It might sound a bit overkill at first, but as it is a very common pattern, you would certainly end up re-using that code often.

Comment: It is a bit slow because you store things in a temp table that you don't have to store at all.

Comment: a single bulk insert into a temp table is not going to be very onerous.