# split a row in a table into multiple rows by parsing the string value in the column

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, tokenize

I need to split a row into multiple rows.

sample value in a column is like this.

```
Message for status: warnings: [w1,w2] | errors: [e1,e2] | other_errors: [e3]
```

Above total message is in one column value.
I need to split it multiple rows like

```
w1
w2
e1
e2
e3
```

- Can some one help me how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting comma separated string in a PL/SQL stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004377/splitting-comma-separated-string-in-a-pl-sql-stored-proc)

Comment: For the purpose of a select, or are you inserting these rows into another table?

Comment: I need this in select.

Comment: Output if the select query should get me the result like this. Which may be stored in another table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method for splitting into columns:

```
select
  ltrim(regexp_substr(translate(col1,'[]',',,'),',([^,]+)', 1,1) ,',') s1,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(translate(col1,'[]',',,'),',([^,]+)', 1,2) ,',') s2,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(translate(col1,'[]',',,'),',([^,]+)', 1,4) ,',') s3,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(translate(col1,'[]',',,'),',([^,]+)', 1,5) ,',') s4,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(translate(col1,'[]',',,'),',([^,]+)', 1,7) ,',') s5
from
  t1;
```

Then you need to unpivot it, and there are plenty of examples on SE.