# Split one column value into multiple columns - stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table called product which contains a column called 'Description'. The values of the  description column will be like

```
'NAME:ITEM1;COST:20;QUANTITY:23;'
'NAME:ITEM2;COST:20;QUANTITY:23;'
'NAME:ITEM4;COST:24;QUANTITY:24;'
'NAME:ITEM6;COST:26;QUANTITY:25;'
'NAME:ITEM3;COST:27;QUANTITY:27;'
```

Now I have another table called `PRODUCT_DETAILS` which has three columns `NAME`, `COST`, `QUANTITY`.

I have to split the values by `':',';'` and extract the values alone into the `PRODUCT_DETAILS` table.

I should use stored procedure to do this. Please help me to sort this out as I had written only simple queries and stored procedures in SQL

Comment: is this mysql or oracle?

Comment: Are you familiar on Oracle's `REGEXP` functionality?  If yes - use it, otherwise learn it. You may want to use [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting comma separated string in a PL/SQL stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004377/splitting-comma-separated-string-in-a-pl-sql-stored-proc)

Comment: Deleted the tag just now

Comment: Thanks everyone. Can I have any sample. I have tried many solutions including the suggestions above. But couldn't get a solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a stored procedure for this. As you know the format of description you can easily select the values and insert them into product_details:

```
insert into product_details
(name, cost, quantity)
select 
  substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 1) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 1) - instr(description, ':', 1, 1) - 1) as name,
  to_number(substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 2) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 2) - instr(description, ':', 1, 2) - 1)) as cost,
  to_number(substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 3) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 3) - instr(description, ':', 1, 3) - 1)) as quantity
from product;
```

Of course you can also write a procedure containing the statement:

```
create or replace procedure product_to_product_details is
begin
  insert into product_details
  (name, cost, quantity)
  select 
    substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 1) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 1) - instr(description, ':', 1, 1) - 1) as name,
    to_number(substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 2) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 2) - instr(description, ':', 1, 2) - 1)) as cost,
    to_number(substr(description, instr(description, ':', 1, 3) + 1, instr(description, ';', 1, 3) - instr(description, ':', 1, 3) - 1)) as quantity
  from product;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample query that will help you split the data out:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'.*NAME:([^;]+);.*','\1') AS name
  ,REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'.*COST:([^;]+);.*','\1') AS cost
  ,REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'.*QUANTITY:([^;]+);.*','\1') AS quantity
FROM SplitStringTest;
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1d6e/25) to demonstrate.  Regex is a very handy tool for this sort of thing.

Here are some references:

[Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it works for you.  If so, please consider voting up the answers that helped and accepting the answer that worked.  Best of luck!