# Search each token in a varchar column split with a delimiter

Tags: regex, string, oracle, split

I have table that has columns with email addresses delimited by `;`:

```
TO                                              CC                                  BCC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc.def@xyz.com;an.yes@xyz.com;no.yes@xyz.com   anna.chris@xyz.com;DL_ABC@xyz.com   raj.alb@xyz.com;doug.amb@xyz.com
```

User gives an email address as the search criteria and I have to lookup against each of these columns to find the rows where any of the colums have the target email address.

Can anyone please help me out here?

I tried using `reg_exp` but dont have much experience there.

Comment: Show your attempt please.

Comment: Try [INSTR](http://psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html) instead of reg_exp.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way:

```
SELECT * FROM emailtable
WHERE INSTR(';' || to || ';' || cc || ';' || bcc || ';'
           ,';' || :search_parameter || ';') > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,  Thanks for the input,I am able to get the output .But there is slight complexity here.User has an option to select the input as begins with/contains/ends with.user might not have the complete email address.can we use % character and can we modify the query.

Comment: In that case you'll need to parse the columns out - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004377/splitting-comma-separated-string-in-a-pl-sql-stored-proc

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement and from what I get from your comment on Jeffery Kemp's answer, I suggest you try the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM emailtable
 WHERE lower(REPLACE ("TO" || ';' || cc || ';' || bcc, ' ', ''))
       LIKE '%' || lower(REPLACE (:search_parameter, ' ', '')) || '%'
```

The `lower` function helps us with a case insensitive search. `REPLACE` eliminates the spaces.

I hope this should give you a clue. This is the simplest way in which a part of email ID can be searched through the to, cc and bcc columns. Please modify the `WHERE` condition as per you requirements.

Comment: Hi Rachcha, the problem with your approach is that if the column contains space between the semi-colon and email it doesnt work.

Comment: What is your search string? Can you give me a few sample search strings?

Comment: Hi Rachcha,  consider columns to=cc=bcc= "  Syed.hussain@xyz.com  ;  Rajesh.S.Prabhu@xyz.com  ;  d.Saus@xyz.com  " if user gives entry d.saus and criteria begins with

Comment: What is the difference between user entry and criteria in your case?

Comment: suppose user is not aware of the complete mail id but he knows email starts with d.saus/syed/Rajesh.so he gives d.saus/syed/Rajesh and selects a drop down which has criteria Begins with/Contains/Ends with.In this case begins with

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.