# How to avoid footer using UTL function in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, aql

I  have a csv file having header ,data and footer. The file(ABC.csv) look like this :

```
 "A00",391,3456                  --- header
 "abcd",2324,"sdddd",58955
 "dfgg",3444,"fffff',14455
 "Z99",2                         ----footer
```

I am using UTL function to load this data to table .
Can any one tell me how to avoid footer while loading this file .

Comment: Perhaps you can show your existing code? It'll be easier to explain how to change what you have. And also mention whether the format is fixed - looks like Z99 denotes it's the footer and won't appear anywhere else, but maybe not.

Comment: Yes last line  is footer.Please  can you provide me code for above example to avoid footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, can give you lazy instructions: here is the import funtion https://community.oracle.com/message/3250798#3250798 , you only should add your CSV line split and skip `HEADER` and `FOOTER`.
Split line is here [Splitting comma separated string in a PL/SQL stored proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004377/splitting-comma-separated-string-in-a-pl-sql-stored-proc). To skip header you should add yet another `UTL_FILE.get_line`, to skip footer you can look on one line ahead, to check if end is here.