# Split varchar2 variable based on vertical line delimiter

Tags: variables, plsql, oracle11g, split, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following plsql code

```
DECLARE
   v_personal_info VARCHAR2(100);
   v_name VARCHAR2(100);
   v_signature VARCHAR2(100);
   CURSOR c_personal_info
   IS
     select personal_info from users where name is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR lr_row IN c_personal_info
  LOOP
    v_personal_info := lr_row.personal_info;
    -- Need to split v_personal_info based on |
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Typical values of `v_personal_info` will look like `'Aniket Thakur | athakur'` and I need to split this to different variables like

```
v_name := 'Aniket Thakur'
v_signature := 'athakur'
```

How should I do that. Is there any in built function that does a split based on predefined delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of `v_personal_info` are uniform and always of the structure `string_1`+`|`+`string_2`, then you can easily use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm).

In that case, your procedure can be written as follows:

```
DECLARE
   v_personal_info VARCHAR2(100);
   v_name VARCHAR2(100);
   v_signature VARCHAR2(100);
   CURSOR c_personal_info
   IS
     select personal_info from users where name is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR lr_row IN c_personal_info
  LOOP
    v_personal_info := lr_row.personal_info;
    v_name := REGEXP_SUBSTR ( v_personal_info, '^[^|]*');
    v_signature := REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_personal_info,'[^|]*$')
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Of course practically the procedure is not useful unless you write these values somewhere.

However, if you want a generic way of splitting strings using different delimiters, then you'll have to create your own function. There are multiple examples here to do that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-pl-sql) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004377/splitting-comma-separated-string-in-a-pl-sql-stored-proc)

There is very nice article written by one of the SO users [Split single comma delimited string into rows in Oracle](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

Hawks answer works fine but I prefer not to use regex so I use simple `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` methods.

```
DECLARE
   v_personal_info VARCHAR2(100);
   v_name VARCHAR2(100);
   v_signature VARCHAR2(100);
   delimitIndex number;
   CURSOR c_personal_info
   IS
     select personal_info from users where name is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR lr_row IN c_personal_info
  LOOP
    v_personal_info := lr_row.personal_info;
    delimitIndex := INSTR(v_personal_info, '|');
    if delimitIndex != 0 then
        v_name := SUBSTR(v_personal_info, 1, delimitIndex - 1);
        v_signature := SUBSTR(v_personal_info, delimitIndex+1, LENGTH(v_personal_info)-delimitIndex);
    END if;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```