# ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 2024 bytes (kxs-heap-c,kghsstk)

Tags: oracle11g, out-of-memory

I went for the solution from the **ORA-01795 Error** through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253851/ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000/5254474#5254474), the answer of `d-live`.
After successfully forming `sql` statement I triggered in **sql developer**, I found this issue like

```
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 2024 bytes (kxs-heap-c,kghsstk)
04030. 00000 -  "out of process memory when trying to allocate %s bytes (%s,%s)"  
*Cause:    Operating system process private memory has been exhausted  
*Action:
```

please help me for this issue, I should handle and execute it anyway.

**Note:** total records i am processing is **5341** in `join statement` instead of `in statement` based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253851/ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000/5254474#5254474) solution

Answer (score 0):

This ORA-04030 can be caused by a shortage of RAM on a dedicated (non shared server) environment, a too small PGA, and by not setting kernel parameters large enough to allow enough RAM.  The ORA-04030 is also common when running an import.