# Taking XOR of two arrays in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario in which i need to pass 'name ids' in CSV format string as bind parameter to a SQL Query, and check for if any of that id is present in a table. Its kind of XOR of array of ids with the table name-id in a column in table .

I am not able to get how this can be done(array to column comparision). Could you point me in that direction?

I cannot use Java , or PL/Sql as my query would be used by another team which does processing in runtime.

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to best split csv strings in oracle 9i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you bind multiple values, not single string, 
you can make a table from your csv values:

```
select column_value as id 
from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('linia 1','linia 2','linia 3'))
```

And use a statement like this to make the xor

```
select a.id,b.id 
from 
  table a
  full outer join
    (query)b
  on a.id=b.id
```

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**: I found [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/11692/452651/0/#msg_452651) a query making a table from a value in csv format:

```
with query2 as (
    select substr(:mylist,
                  instr(','||:mylist||',', ',', 1, rn),
                  instr(','||:mylist||',', ',', 1, rn+1)
                  - instr(','||:mylist||',', ',', 1, rn) - 1) value
    from (select rownum rn from dual 
         connect by level 
                       <= length(:mylist)-length(replace(:mylist,',',''))+1)
    )
  select value
  from query2
```

Answer (score 0):

in oracle 10g and above You can convert a single csv parameter (mycsv) to columns using :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycsv,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) element                           
FROM dual                       
CONNECT BY LEVEL < LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(mycsv,'[^,]+')) + 1
```

Then use the `IN` clause and the above as a sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE id IN ( ....the query above... )
```