# Oracle: using IN clause with text field?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, token

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to best split csv strings in oracle 9i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i)

I have some legacy data where there's a `VARCHAR2(100)` field `SUBID` that has comma-delimited data:

```
empno   subid
1       1, 3, 2
2       18,19, 3, 6, 9
```

etc.

I need to write the equivalent of

```
select * 
  from table 
 where id in ( select SUBID from subidtable where empno = 1 )
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Oracle?

Edit:

Added some clarification. I need to do the `IN` clause against the values stored in a string from a single row, not all rows.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to find records in `table` where `table.id` is in *any* `subidtable.subid`? Like, with the example data you posted, would you need to find all records in `table` with `id` in `(1,2,3,6,9,18,19)`?

Comment: Can you normalize this table? I.e. can you create another table and convert the comma-separated values into individual numbers?

Comment: What is the data type of your `id` field from `table` in your example?  You should be able to use the `IN` clause with Oracle as long as the data types match (or else convert it).

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur - No, the problem is that SUBID is a comma delimited string of integers.  Using `IN` on it's own (as shown in the OPs existing example) will not give the necessary results, as `(SELECT subid FROM subidtable)` is a set of strings consisting of numerics and commas, and *not* a set of integers.

Comment: @chris - I was initially assuming you wanted your IN clause to look at a particular row's `SUBID` column (i.e. either 1,3,2 or 18,19,3,6,9).  Do you really want to combine all the values in all the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it's a little ugly.  Depending on the Oracle version

You can use a variant of [this askTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425) to parse the data into a collection and use the collection in your SQL statement.  This should work in any version of Oracle since 8.1.5 but the syntax has gotten a bit simpler over the years.

```
SQL> create or replace type myTableType as table
  2       of varchar2 (255);
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace
  2       function in_list( p_string in varchar2 ) return myTableType
  3    as
  4        l_string        long default p_string || ',';
  5        l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
  6        n               number;
  7    begin
  8      loop
  9          exit when l_string is null;
 10          n := instr( l_string, ',' );
 11          l_data.extend;
 12          l_data(l_data.count) :=
 13                ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
 14          l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
 15     end loop;
 16     return l_data;
 17*  end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select ename
  2    from emp
  3   where empno in (select column_value
  4                     from table( in_list( '7934, 7698, 7521' )));

ENAME
----------
WARD
BLAKE
MILLER
```

You can also use regular expressions as discussed in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select ename
  2    from emp
  3   where empno in (select regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+',1,level)
  4                     from (select '7934, 7698, 7521' str from dual)
  5*                 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'[^,]+'))
SQL> /

ENAME
----------
WARD
MILLER
BLAKE
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a better way to do it.  There's actually a package in the database that contains a function with your exact code, and even references that particular asktom article in a comment.  So I guess until we can fix the table design, the package lives.

Answer (score 2):

If you can 'fix' your table structure to have a 1:many relationship, such that each row in your `subidtable` contains only *one* `id`, that's your best bet.

If you can't, then you could get hold of one of the *many* `split()` functions that people have coded around the web.  These take a string and return the data as a set.  The problem here is that they are designed to take a single string and return a table of values, not to take a table of strings...

As this data seems to be in a bit of a hacked format, you may only need a one-time hack solution with minimal code.  In such cases you can try this...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM subidtable WHERE (',' || subid || ',') LIKE ('%,' || table.id || ',%'))
```

But be warned, it scales VERY badly.  So expect slow performance if you have a large amount of data in either table.

**EDIT**

As your edit now shows that you're only ever processing one string from the `subidtable` table, the split function option becomes a lot easier to implement.  See Justin's answer :)

A modification to the 'simple hack' above would be...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  (SELECT ',' || subid || ',' FROM subidtable WHERE empno=1) LIKE ('%,' || table.id || ',%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way elegant and an abuse of "execute immediate" but in your specific case this might work:

```
DECLARE
  i INTEGER;
  subid VARCHAR2(100) := '18,19, 3, 6, 9';
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select 1  from dual where 6 in (' || subid || ')'
    INTO i;

  dbms_output.put_line('returned: ' || i);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Exception: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```