# WHERE condition for "starts with any of the values in a CSV list"

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, oracle10g, stringtokenizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert csv to table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142665/how-to-convert-csv-to-table-in-oracle)

I have a query in PL/SQL that is built to handle input in a variable as a "starts-with" filter:

```
WHERE product_group LIKE strProductGroup || '%'
```

As a new "feature", the input variable could contain comma separated values.  So, where before I would expect something like "ART", I could now see "ART,DRM".

I'd like to avoid building this query as a string and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, if possible.  Can anyone think of a way to write a WHERE condition that is the equivalent of saying "starts with any of the values in a CSV list" in Oracle 10g?

Comment: maybe you would like to use `product_group in (strProductGroup)`?

Comment: not a duplicate.  the other post is asking about 11g and I also have the "starts-with" requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i) that gave me an idea.  In my specific case, the values in the input will all be 3 characters, so I can do the following:

```
AND SUBSTR(product_group, 0, 3) IN
    (SELECT regexp_substr(strProductGroup, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace(strProductGroup, '[^,]+')) + 1)
```

I like this solution, because it does not require additional types or functions, but is pretty limited to my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't have any restrictions on creating a couple of additional objects (a collection type and a function), you can parse the list into a collection that you can reference in your query.  Tom Kyte has a good discussion on this in his [variable "IN" list](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425) thread.

If you use Tom's `myTableType` and `in_list` function, for example

```
SQL> create or replace type myTableType as table 
     of varchar2 (255);
  2  /

Type created.


ops$tkyte@dev8i> create or replace 
     function in_list( p_string in varchar2 ) return myTableType
  2  as
  3      l_string        long default p_string || ',';
  4      l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
  5      n               number;
  6  begin
  7    loop
  8        exit when l_string is null;
  9        n := instr( l_string, ',' );
10         l_data.extend;
11         l_data(l_data.count) := 
                 ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
12         l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
13    end loop;
14
15    return l_data;
16  end;
17  /
```

Then you can search for equality relatively easily.

```
WHERE product_group IN (SELECT column_value 
                          FROM TABLE( in_list( strProductGroup )))
```

But you want to do a `LIKE` which is a bit more challenging since you can't do a `LIKE` on an in-list.  You could, however, do something like

```
select *
  from emp e,
       (select '^' || column_value search_regexp
          from table( in_list( 'KIN,BOB' ))) a
 where regexp_like( e.ename, a.search_regexp )
```

This will search the `EMP` table for any employees where the `ENAME` begins with either `KIN` or `BOB`.  In the default `SCOTT.EMP` table, this will return just one row, the row where the `ENAME` is "KING"

Comment: adding a PIPELINED would be quite handy, wouldn't it?

Comment: @gpeche - It wouldn't hurt.  Assuming the string fits in a `VARCHAR2`, though, it's limited to 32k.  If each search term is 3 bytes with a 4th byte for the comma, that means there are a maximum of 8k terms.  That's  a pretty reasonable number of elements to have in a collection without needing to pipeline the results.  It wouldn't hurt to pipeline the results, but it does add a touch of complexity.

Comment: Also, it is important to remember to have a look at the execution plan, as some Oracle versions get quite confused about the table type. Sometimes you need to add a `cardinality` or `materialize` hint to get Oracle to do the right thing.