# oracle function that accept comma separated value and return in rows

Tags: oracle, tokenize

i am looking for an oracle function that accepts comma seperated values eg,[abc,cde] and 
return me rows so that i can insert into a table directly.

eg-:

```
insert into mytable(col)
select mycustomfunction (abc,cde)
```

Comment: Search for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+%2Bsplit+column+%2Brow

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to best split csv strings in oracle 9i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089508/how-to-best-split-csv-strings-in-oracle-9i)